# Mono setup issue in RHEL 5 due to bison setup issue

Tags: linux, mono, bison, rhel, rhel5

I am trying to install mono on my RHEL 5. While running the configure script i get the following error:

checking for bison... no
configure: error: You need to install bison

But i already have bison installed on my machine:
which bison
/usr/local/bin/bison

When i tried re-running the config script for mono with the bison path specified i get the same error:
 sudo ./configure --with-bibon=/usr/local/bin

checking for bison... no
configure: error: You need to install bison

Kindly help me in this setup issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite a bad idea to run `sudo` for the `configure`, `make`, and `make check` steps, keep that for `make install`.  Check `./configure --help` to see if there is really a `--with-bison` option (which is certainly not spelled `--with-bidon`).  Finally, have a look at the `config.log` file which probably contains details about why `bison` was not recognized.